# Excluding a DE from Contact Deletion

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, mobileconnect, contact-deletion

I have a question about Contact Deletion: How could I proceed if I want to exclude from Contact Deletion of All Contacts, a DE that is populated daily with the contacts injected in JB through Salesforce Data Event? I would like to proceed with automation without using rest api. Do you have any idea?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Deletions don't remove contacts from non-sendable Data extension, so maybe:

- create a copy of your data extension and make it not sendable
- copy data from you original DE to the new one
- make the API call deleting customers after you're done

Comment: Hi, thank you for you response, but i want to exclude DE from Contact Deletion. I have a DE master (with all contacts) and I want to exclude from this one, a DE that works with a particular JB

Comment: I will recommend you to follow Rafal's advice. Creating non-sendable shadow DE will also be my recommendation

Comment: Ok @LukasLunow, thank you. If I enable Contact Deletion on the parent BU, in order to exclude DE that is in a child Business Unit, i must create a Shared Data Extension and then an Automation in parent BU?

Comment: @Nap - creating a non-shared DE in child, and populating it using Query in same BU would suffice.

Comment: @LukasLunow And in this way how can I exclude the DE that is in the child business unit if I have to do Contact Deletion from the parent bu? Should I still create an automation to exclude DE? For contact deletion I intend to act through cancellation with mobile connect and not using REST API.

Comment: @Nap - non-sendable data extensions are, per design, not affected by contact deletion framework, as it relies on identifying the records based on the Subscriber Key mapping.

Comment: @LukasLunow I explain my problem better: there is an active jb powered by salesforce data event. DE is populated every day. My intention is therefore not to remove from the contact deletion this DE that must remain active. To do this i thought to extract All Contacts and later, through a sql query, i exclude this de (but to do it i must make it shared data extension). Do you think it is correct?

Comment: @Nap - you can't exclude a data extension from contact deletion. This can only be done by making it non-sendable. You can exclude the Subscriber Keys in your journey data extension when creating a list of contacts to delete. This will ensure none of the records in your JB DE will be removed. If these contacts are located anywhere else in your platform, these records will also be kept.

Comment: @LukasLunow So, could I create a copy of DE but only with the contact key and then share it in the Parent BU in such a way as to create an automation in the parent (I want to create a sql query activity that queries DE with All Contacts and also exclude DE of JB)?